# Error in file(con, "wb") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

Coding in R Studio.
Trying to replicate the demo outlined here:
https://wcmbishop.github.io/rayshader-demo/.

When trying to run his get elevation UDF, I run into the following error:

```
> elev_file <- file.path("data", "brussels.tif")
> get_usgs_elevation_data(bbox, size = image_size$size, file = elev_file,
+                         sr_bbox = 4326, sr_image = 4326) 
    Error in file(con, "wb") : cannot open the connection 
In addition: Warning message: In file(con, "wb") :    
Error in file(con, "wb") : cannot open the connection
```

I am quite new to R and programming/coding in general, and have no idea what this is trying to tell me. I've looked online, but without much success.

Comment: `file.exists(elev_file)` is true?

Comment: @r2evans: Error in file.exists(elev_file) : object 'elev_file' not found

Comment: Ummm ... *that's your object*. Are you creating that object or not? Regardless, does `file.exists("data/brussels.tif")` return true?

Comment: I think so? You can inspect my code here. Disregard anything past line 137 :) 

https://github.com/Jonathan-121/Rayshader_Trial/blob/main/Rayshader%20Trial.R

Comment: file.exists("data/brussels.tif") returns, FALSE, I'm not sure how to proceed, however

Comment: (1/2) You need to work out what your *working directory* is or should be. Every process has a directory from which everything is referenced. You can work around this by not caring, and making every file/dir reference "absolute", starting at the root (e.g., `c:\\` on windows, or `/` on macos and unix-y variants). Or ... you can *know* where your current process is based and make references relative to that.

Comment: (2/2) Some references: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces, https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/the-working-directory.html, and of course [`?getwd`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/getwd.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans, I'll take a look and revert if I can't figure it out! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### R can't read the file you've specified

This could be caused by a few things:

- The file doesn't exist in the working directory
- R doesn't have permission to read the file

R is looking for "data/brussels.tif" in your working directory, which you can see by running `getwd()`. The working directory can change (for example, when you run `setwd()`).

`file.exists("data/brussels.tif")` will return `TRUE` if "data/brussels.tf" exists in the current wd, or `FALSE` if it does not. If it returns `FALSE`, that's your problem. If it returns `TRUE`, it may be that R can see the file, but doesn't have permission to read it.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for this! 
Changing the wd helped. 

I also came to realise that I was going to ping a database for elevation data it does not have (can’t ask a US database for Belgian elevation data...). 

I’m now hitting a different error, but we can consider this question closed. 

Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped Jonathan. If this post answered your question, could you accept it as the answer? That way others with the same problem can see that there's a solution.